# Как убрать путь до файла в консоли PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains

Во время исполнения программы в PyCharm в окне Run отображается путь до файла, где находиться программа, как мне отключить отображение этого?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176552/how-to-hide-file-paths-when-running-python-scripts-in-vs-code) аналогичный вопрос про VS Code. Может, есть что-то полезное.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, это нельзя отключить.

Но можно открыть `File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Colors - System output`, потом изменить цвет на `1E1F22` (цвет фона), чтобы путь к файлу стал невидимым